# Effect on performance by order of indexed columns

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table called '`notifications`'

```
dateTime | message | sentStatus | sentDateTime | sensorID | userID
```

I have created an index on this table for `(dateTime, sensorID)`.

I have read somewhere, in MySQL, indexes work from left to right.

I am querying the data like this

```
SELECT dateTime, message 
WHERE sensorID = 'id' 
  AND sentStatus != 'sent' 
ORDER BY dateTime desc;
```

Is my query making any use of the indexes ?

Will there be any effect on performance if I changed the order of the columns like this?

```
userID | sensorID | dateTime | message | sentStatus | sentDateTime
```

Comment: Changing the order of columns in table won't affect index. Changing the order of columns the index is based will do, however: index on `(dateTime, sensorId)` won't be hit when `sensorId` is queried. But there are too many factors there; why don't you check the results of `EXPLAIN`-ing your query?

Comment: Is there anyway to improve the performance of the above query for the given table ?

Answer (score 2):

The proper index should be:

```
(sensorID, status, dateTime)
```

First two because are part of the where condition, the last one for the sorting.

Check MySQL index [**TIPS**](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)